# How do I break up a string to single character strings in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

My input is a string and I need to be able to analyze it lexically and I'd like to know how to decompose it into single character strings and analyze each character individually.

Comment: note that characters and strings are different, so a character is not the same as a length-1 string. which one do you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html

Example:

```
> (string->list "Apple")

  '(#\A #\p #\p #\l #\e)
```

Comment: You guys are the best. Definitely life savers!